# How to explain this algorithm for calculating the power of a number?

Tags: algorithm

I am currently reading Skiena's "The Algorithm Design Manual".

He describes an algorithm for calculating the power of a number i.e. calculate `a^n`.

He begins by saying that the simplest algorithm is simply `a*a*a ... *a`, so we have a total of `n-1` calculations.

He then goes on to say that there is an optimisation for that, and asks us to recognise that:

```
n = n/2 + n/2
```

and we can also say that

```
a^n = ((a^n/2)^2)  (a to the n equals a to the n over 2, squared)
```

Which I understand so far. From these equations, he deduces an algorithm which performs only `O(lg n)` multiplications.

```
function power(a, n)
  if (n = 0) 
    return(1)

  x = power(a,n/2)

  if (n is even)       
    return(x^2)
  else             
    return(a*x^2)
```

It appears that `x` must be the current value computed so far. But still after reading this several times, I don't understand how from those equations he designed this algorithm, or even how it works. Can anyone explain?

Comment: Its a recursive process of calling the function power.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all, let's fix your algorithm:

```
function power( a, n )
    if (n = 0) 
        return(1)

    x = power(a,n/2)

    if (n is even) 
        return(x*x)
    else 
        return(a*x*x)
```

Say you want to calculate `power(2,8)`, that is, `2^8` (`^` is not `XOR` here, of course).

- 1) (`a=2`, `n=8`). `2^8 = (2^4)^2`, so we have to calculate `x=2^4`, and then `x*x` to yield the final result. We have to call `power()` again to get `x`. `power(2,4)`.
- 2) (`a=2`, `n=4`). `2^4 = (2^2)^2`, so we have to calculate `x=2^2`, and then `x*x` to yield the final result.  We have to call `power()` again to get `x`. `power(2,2)`.
- 3) (`a=2`, `n=2`). `2^2 = (2^1)^2`, so we have to calculate `x=2^1`, and then `x*x` to yield the final result.  We have to call `power()` again to get `x`. `power(2,1)`.
- 4) (`a=2`, `n=1`). `2^1 = (2^0)^2`, so we have to calculate `x=2^0`, and then `a*x*x` to yield the final result.  We have to call `power()` again to get `x`. `power(2,0)`.
- 5) (`a=2`, `n=0`). `2^0 = 1` because `n` is `0`, so we have the value of `x` that is returned to step #4.
- 4) (`a=2`, `n=1`, `x=1`). The final result for this step is `a*x*x = 2*1*1=2`, which is the value to be assigned to `x` in step #3.
- 3) (`a=2`, `n=2`, `x=2`). The final result for this step is `x*x = 2*2 = 4`. This is the result to be assigned to `x` in step #2.
- 2) (`a=2`, `n=4`, `x=4`). The final result for this step is `x*x = 4*4 = 16`. This is the result to be assigned to `x` in step #1.
- 1) (`a=2`, `n=8`, `x=16`). The final result for this step is `x*x = 16*16 = 256`. This is the result to be returned by `power(2,8)`.

Answer (score 21):

The concept is simple. For example, compute the value of 3<sup>8</sup>

You can use the obvious way  which is 3<sup>8</sup> = 3 x 3 x 3 x 3 x 3 x 3 x 3 x 3 which takes 7 multiplication operations. Or there is a better way.

Let say that

- If we know the value 3<sup>4</sup>, we can compute 3<sup>8</sup> only in one multiplication operation, but we don't know the value of 3<sup>4</sup>
- If we know the value of 3<sup>2</sup>, we can compute 3<sup>4</sup> in one multiplication operation.
- And finally, we know that 3<sup>2</sup> can be easily compute by 3 x 3.

Going backward, it only takes 3 multiplication to compute 3<sup>8</sup> instead of 7

Here is the clearly view of the process:

```
   32 = 3 x 3 = 9
   34 = 32 x 32 = 9 x 9 = 81
   38 = 34 x 34 = 81 x 81 = 6,561
```

Then, there is another problem, what if the power is odd number. For example: 3<sup>9</sup>, how to deal with it? You can either do this

```
   39 = 3 x 38   or
   39 = 3 x 34 x 34
```

---

Lets call the algorithm that continuously multiple the number as *Method A*, and algorithm that continuously divide the power by two as *Method B*. How good is method A comparing to method B? For a small number such as 3<sup>8</sup>, there is not much significant improvement, even those, we minimize the number of multiplication, but we also slightly increase the number of division operation.

So for 3<sup>8</sup>

```
               Multiplication   Division
   Method A:        7              0
   Method B:        3              3
```

However, for the larger power, for example: 3<sup>4,294,967,296</sup>

```
               Multiplication   Division
   Method A:   4,294,967,295       0
   Method B:       32              32
```

The difference is huge.

Comment: I like your explanation but I have accepted mcleod's answer because I think he goes into the basics step by step. But now I have understood the algorithm, reading through your answer is extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = power(a, n/2)
```

will give you a^n/2. If even this whole statement is squared giving (a^n/2)^2. Now if  n is odd, during n/2 a power of a^1 is lost so to get it back it is multiplied with a. This is according to the equation given.

Comment: How will `n` ever become 0? I am confused as to how this algorithm will ever terminate.

Comment: @patchwork: In your algorithm, `n / 2` is an integer division, not a floating point division. So, 5/2 is 2 with a remainder of 1, not 2.5. Eventually, you'll reach 0 by integer-dividing any integer. (Some languages use special syntax such as a double slash to denote integer division: `n // 2`. Typed languages treat division of two integral types as integer division.) Tho possible remainders of 0 and 1 of this integer div by 2 are the reason for branching on odd and even numbers when returning the power.

Answer (score 0):

This function is recursive, meaning that when called, it is going to call itself over and over again until some final condition is met. In this case, there are three final conditions that will stop the function from calling itself and return the result.

If I were you I would try to apply the algorithm manually on a couple of different values in order to understand.

Answer (score 0):

This formula `a^n = ((a^n/2)^2)`, which you understand dictates recursive algorithm.

To get `a^n` you need first to calculate `a^(n/2)`, 
To get `a^(n/2)`, you need to calculate `a^((n/2)/2)`, 
... and so on, until `(n/2/2/...2)` reaches 0, which is the termination condition of the recursion.

So, the recursive algorithm follows that formula exactly :

to get `power(a,n)` you first recursively calculate `power(a,n/2)` and then return the result adjusting for `n` being odd/even number.

There is also [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) article about this implementation.

Comment: Does successively dividing by 2 ever reach 0?

Comment: Yes, always. When you divide by 2 you only take integer part of the division. So, 3 / 2 = 1, and 1 / 2 = 0;

Comment: The terminating value is 1 if you consider the limiting value of `(n/2/2/2.../2)`.

Comment: @chepner not according to this line : `if (n = 0) 
    return(1)`

Comment: `n/2` is never going to equal zero. It's a bug/typo in the function as presented. The case where `n` is odd requires a subtraction by 1, not division by 2 (which, I now realize, does lead to a termination condition of 0).

Answer (score 0):

The function `power(...)` appears to be written the way it is to handle the effects of integer division. Recall that under integer division rules, the fractional part is discarded. This will only affect odd integers since an even integer divided by two produces no remainder.

Thus whenever `n` is an even integer, the value computed for `n/2` is exactly equal to `n/2` and the top branch of the `if` can be taken: this is exactly what the equations stipulate.

Whenever `n` is an odd integer, the value computed for `n/2` is actually equal to `floor(n/2)`. In other words, the statement:

```
x = power(a,n/2)
```

Has actually computed the result

```
x = power(a,(n-1)/2)
```

Meaning that you have permanently lost one 1 from your exponent, and simply returning `x^2` will be short one power of `a`. Hence the bottom branch, which adds back in the power of `a`.

If you imagine that instead of integer division, the computer was capable of perfectly lossless real number division, then you could rewrite the function as:

```
function power( a, n )

    if (n = 0) 
        return(1)

    x = power(a,n/2)

    return x^2
```

You can easily satisfy yourself that this is a simple recursive implementation of the second equation you provided in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing the entire chain of operations as a one-liner (which you can directly run with `bc`) really helps with understanding exactly what the algorithm is trying to do at each stage :

> - Count up the asterisks (`*`) for total # of **multiplications**

---

> - Count up the carets (`^`) for total # of **squarings**

```
  29 ^ 1847  
| expn LSB bitstring := 11101100111
| 29*(29*(29*((29*(29*(((29*(29*(29)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2


  29 ^ 4373  
| expn LSB bitstring := 1010100010001
| 29*((29*((29*((((29*((((29)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2


  29 ^ 8563  
| expn LSB bitstring := 11001110100001
| 29*(29*(((29*(29*(29*((29*(((((29)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2


  29 ^ 8689  
| expn LSB bitstring := 10001111100001
| 29*((((29*(29*(29*(29*(29*(((((29)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2


  29 ^ 9067  
| expn LSB bitstring := 11010110110001
| 29*(29*((29*((29*(29*((29*(29*((((29)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2


  29 ^ 11197 
| expn LSB bitstring := 10111101110101
| 29*((29*(29*(29*(29*((29*(29*(29*((29*((29)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2


  29 ^ 14813 
| expn LSB bitstring := 10111011100111
| 29*((29*(29*(29*((29*(29*(29*(((29*(29*(29)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2


  29 ^ 15749 
| expn LSB bitstring := 10100001101111
| 29*((29*(((((29*(29*((29*(29*(29*(29)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2


  29 ^ 16703 
| expn LSB bitstring := 111111001000001
| 29*(29*(29*(29*(29*(29*(((29*((((((29)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2


  29 ^ 18919 
| expn LSB bitstring := 111001111001001
| 29*(29*(29*(((29*(29*(29*(29*(((29*(((29)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2


  29 ^ 24071 
| expn LSB bitstring := 111000000111101
| 29*(29*(29*(((((((29*(29*(29*(29*((29)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2


  29 ^ 24371 
| expn LSB bitstring := 110011001111101
| 29*(29*(((29*(29*(((29*(29*(29*(29*(29*((29)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2


  29 ^ 25933 
| expn LSB bitstring := 101100101010011
| 29*((29*(29*(((29*((29*((29*(((29*(29)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2


  29 ^ 26003 
| expn LSB bitstring := 110010011010011
| 29*(29*(((29*(((29*(29*((29*(((29*(29)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2


  29 ^ 27851 
| expn LSB bitstring := 110100110011011
| 29*(29*((29*(((29*(29*(((29*(29*((29*(29)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2


  29 ^ 28097 
| expn LSB bitstring := 100000111011011
| 29*((((((29*(29*(29*((29*(29*((29*(29)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2


  29 ^ 28537 
| expn LSB bitstring := 100111101111011
| 29*(((29*(29*(29*(29*((29*(29*(29*(29*((29*(29)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2


  29 ^ 28603 
| expn LSB bitstring := 110111011111011
| 29*(29*((29*(29*(29*((29*(29*(29*(29*(29*((29*(29)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2


  29 ^ 32869 
| expn LSB bitstring := 1010011000000001
| 29*((29*(((29*(29*(((((((((29)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2


  29 ^ 33013 
| expn LSB bitstring := 1010111100000001
| 29*((29*((29*(29*(29*(29*((((((((29)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2


  29 ^ 33107 
| expn LSB bitstring := 1100101010000001
| 29*(29*(((29*((29*((29*(((((((29)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2


  29 ^ 33529 
| expn LSB bitstring := 1001111101000001
| 29*(((29*(29*(29*(29*(29*((29*((((((29)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2


  29 ^ 33629 
| expn LSB bitstring := 1011101011000001
| 29*((29*(29*(29*((29*((29*(29*((((((29)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2


  29 ^ 33809 
| expn LSB bitstring := 1000100000100001
| 29*((((29*((((((29*(((((29)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2


  29 ^ 36899 
| expn LSB bitstring := 1100010000001001
| 29*(29*((((29*(((((((29*(((29)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2


  29 ^ 38651 
| expn LSB bitstring := 1101111101101001
| 29*(29*((29*(29*(29*(29*(29*((29*(29*((29*(((29)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2


  29 ^ 38839 
| expn LSB bitstring := 1110110111101001
| 29*(29*(29*((29*(29*((29*(29*(29*(29*((29*(((29)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2


  29 ^ 46093 
| expn LSB bitstring := 1011000000101101
| 29*((29*(29*(((((((29*((29*(29*((29)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2


  29 ^ 47279 
| expn LSB bitstring := 1111010100011101
| 29*(29*(29*(29*((29*((29*((((29*(29*(29*((29)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2


  29 ^ 47339 
| expn LSB bitstring := 1101011100011101
| 29*(29*((29*((29*(29*(29*((((29*(29*(29*((29)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2


  29 ^ 52183 
| expn LSB bitstring := 1110101111010011
| 29*(29*(29*((29*((29*(29*(29*(29*((29*(((29*(29)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2


  29 ^ 52697 
| expn LSB bitstring := 1001101110110011
| 29*(((29*(29*((29*(29*(29*((29*(29*(((29*(29)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2


  29 ^ 53569 
| expn LSB bitstring := 1000001010001011
| 29*((((((29*((29*((((29*((29*(29)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2


  29 ^ 59471 
| expn LSB bitstring := 1111001000010111
| 29*(29*(29*(29*(((29*(((((29*((29*(29*(29)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2


  29 ^ 63029 
| expn LSB bitstring := 1010110001101111
| 29*((29*((29*(29*((((29*(29*((29*(29*(29*(29)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2


  29 ^ 63667 
| expn LSB bitstring := 1100110100011111
| 29*(29*(((29*(29*((29*((((29*(29*(29*(29*(29)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2


  29 ^ 65287 
| expn LSB bitstring := 1110000011111111
| 29*(29*(29*((((((29*(29*(29*(29*(29*(29*(29*(29)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2
```

which could be auto generated by this scripting code :

```
gawk 'function ____(__, ___, _) {

    if (_ == "") {

        if ((__ *= (___ = length(__ = (_)__)) \
            * _++ < (__ = int(__))) < ++_)
            return __

        _ ^= (___ += __ + __ < (_+_)^_^_ \
                    ? _ * --___ \
                    : _ * ___ - _^(__ < (_*_^_^_)^_))
        if (__ < _)
            ___ -= __ < (__ += __)
        if (_+_ <= __)
            while ((_+=_+!++___)+_ <= __);

        return (_<__ ? ____(__ -= _, ___, _) \
                   : sprintf("%.*d", ___, !_) !!_
    }
    return !--___ ? !!+__ : (__+=__)<_ ? ____(__, ___, _) !_ \
                                       : ____(__-=_,___,_) !!_
}
BEGIN {
    OFS = ")^2"
} _ = NF {

    printf("\f %11s^%-5s \f\r\t\t| expn LSB bitstring := %*s\f\r\t\t| ",
            __ = $!!_, $!_ = $_, _ = !_, $_ = ____($_)) > ("/dev/stderr")

    print ($!(NF = gsub(/[^01]+/, "")^_ * gsub(_, "(") + gsub(!_,
        __ "*(") * sub(/[^0-9]*$/, "") \
                 * sub(/^$/, !_)^_))) "\n") > ("/dev/stderr") } NF'
```

========

in case you're curious, the smallest odd prime to the power of the largest prime representable by that 64-bit double type has a chain of operations like this :

```
       3 ^ 9007199254740881 
    | expn LSB bitstring := 100010011111111111111111
                            11111111111111111111111111111
```

> 

```
3*(  (  (  (3*(  (  (3*(3*(3*(3*(3*(3*(3*(3*(3*(3*(3*
  (3*(3*(3*(3*(3*(3*(3*(3*(3*(3*(3*(3*(3*(3*(3*(3*(3*
  (3*(3*(3*(3*(3*(3*(3*(3*(3*(3*(3*(3*(3*(3*(3*(3*(3*(3
   \
    )^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2 
    )^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2
    )^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2
```

and a decimal representation of only 4297 trillion digits - any 1785 TB drive should suffice.